# Calculate the limits of the sequence $\frac{2}{n+2}$ from first principles

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

i know that it can then be simplified by saying $\frac{2}{n+2}$ < $\frac{2}{n}$ but then would it just continue as normal saying that you would then choose an integer $N(\epsilon)$ within the set of natural numbers such that $$N(\epsilon) > \frac{2}{\epsilon} $$ possible by Archimedes principle. if someone could talk me through this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to know exactly what to do. What's stopping you?

Comment: Exactly my thoughts ...

Comment: well every other one i've attempted has gone down to $N{\epsilon} > \frac{1}{\epsilon}

Comment: just unsure if this one needs any additional workings or whether you just treat it the same

Comment: looks good.  You need to show that for any $\epsilon$ there exists an $N.$  Which it looks like you have done.

Comment: well in that case thank you very much guys.

Comment: This is fine.  But there is nothing wrong with $n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}-2$.

Comment: @ConnorDavies You need to first have an idea of what the limit $l$ might be. Once you get this you need to prove that $$\forall \varepsilon>0\exists N\in \mathbb N\forall p\in \mathbb N\left(p\ge N\implies \left|\dfrac{2}{n+2}-l\right|<\varepsilon\right)_.$$ You correctly guessed that $l=0$ and you got rid of the absolute value because everything is non-negative. Next you need to take an arbitrary positive real number $\varepsilon$ and find a natural number $N$ such that $\forall p\in \mathbb N\left(p\ge N\implies \left|\dfrac{2}{n+2}-l\right|<\varepsilon\right)$.

Comment: @ConnorDavies Invoking Archimedes you found $N$ such that $N>\dfrac{2}{\varepsilon}$. Does this $N$ work? Check it: let $p$ be an arbitrary natural number greater than (or equal to) $N$. Since $$N>\dfrac{2}{\varepsilon}\implies \ldots\implies \varepsilon>\dfrac{2}{n+2},$$ it follows that $\varepsilon>\dfrac{2}{n+2}$. Rewriting this inequality a bit yields $\left|\dfrac{2}{n+2}-l\right|<\varepsilon$, QED.

Comment: cleared it up completely, thank you @GitGud

Answer (score 2):

We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n+2}=0$. Here, the inequality $|\frac{2}{n+2}-0|<\varepsilon$ gives $n > \frac{2-2\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$ and hence any $N >\frac{2(1-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}$  will do.